# How to define a shared (global) variable in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I need a shared (global) variable which is accessible among all mappers and reducers. Mappers just read value from it, but reducers change some values to be used in the next iteration in it. I know DistributedCache is a technique to do that, however it only support reading a shared value.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) was built for. ZooKeeper can keep up with lots of reads from mappers/reducers, and still be able to write something now and then.

The other option would be to [set values in the configuration object](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html#set%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). However, this only persists globally for a single job. You'd have to manage the passing of this value across jobs yourself. Also, you can't end this while the job is running.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to do it just by distributedCache? I mean reading from distributedCache is straightforward. However, for updating the values, can I create a new file in the main program and use it in the next iteration to fill up the distributedCache?

Comment: you can pretty much only write to the distributed cache at the beginning of a job. so if you have the ability to do so, you can do that.

Comment: tnx a lot. I really appreciate.